# Product creation / management software for physical appliance

Tags: project-management, product-management

I'm looking for product management software. I don't mean *project* management software like Jira, Redmine or new agile ones like PivotalTracker.

I mean software to manage (and possibly design) a physical product, something similar to [ProdPad](https://www.prodpad.com/) that also covers rest of product lifecycle.

The software has to be able to:

- Create specifications
- Manage part suppliers
- Generate bill of material
- Create assembly information / guides

Basically I'm looking for something like ProdPad that would allow me to manage product from start to finish: Idea(s) → Design (including box design, etc.) → Creating BoM → Manufacturing → Packaging.

Products I'd like to create are physical ones, mainly based on embeded electronics so integration with part suppliers and design software would be a huge plus.

Platforms: Preferably a desktop application (preferably with Linux support, but I can live with Windows), I'd also consider a web app.

Can be paid up to 1000$

Answer (score 1):

PTC Creo seems to have most or all of what you need.  You can get a basic idea of features from the right column of [this comparison chart](http://www.ptc.com/File%20Library/Product%20Families/Creo/Comparison_Creo_Parametric_Vs_Pro-Engineer.pdf).  You can [contact the company](http://www.ptc.com/product/creo/how-to-buy) with your specific needs and see if they can provide what you need within your budget.